# react-router-dom v4 router is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

router is not working.
localhost:3000/, localhost:3000/#/, localhost:3000/#/aa ==> all moves in home page.

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/aa"  component={Main}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const lunaRocketModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'luna-rocket');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        '@babel/polyfill',
        path.join(__dirname,'src/app','app.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'build'),
        filename: 'index.bundle.js'
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    resolve: {
        alias: {

        },
        extensions: [
            '.js',
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'src')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // this is so that we can compile any React,
                // ES6 and above into normal ES5 syntax
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                // we do not want anything from node_modules to be compiled
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
                loaders: ['file-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname,'src','index.html')
        }),
    ]
};
```

how to move aa??? please help me.
i don't why router is not working.
and url in # is what is meaning in react??
if localhost:3000/aa--> devServer is working
 if localhost:3000/#/aa ==> Home page

(React 16, babel7, wepack4)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really identify was wrong here, but try removing the `<Switch></Switch>` around the routes and also `<Route exact path="/aa"  component={Main}/>`
without exact this also matches the first route

Answer (score 0):

Actually with `/#/aa` you are just routing towards `/` because `#` specifies an "Anchor", or a position on the page, and allows you to "jump" or "scroll" to that position on the page.

your `Main` will be available at localhost:3000/aa